# Laravel: Is this example of pessimistic locking correct?

Tags: php, laravel-5, locking, innodb

I want to notify each user that has not been notified for one week.

The code looks like this:

```
// Select all users where attribute `notified` is older then one week
$users = \App\User::lastNotified(7)->get();

foreach($users as $user){
   $user->notifed = date('Y-m-d');
   \Mail::to($user)send(new NotificationMail($user));
   $user->save();
}
```

I want to make sure that if the code is executed parallel that each user will receive only one notification (no duplicates).

Have I understand it correctly that I have to use for this [Pessimistic Locking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#pessimistic-locking) like this:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
   $users = \App\User::lastNotified(7)->lockForUpdate()->get();

    foreach($users as $user){
       $user->notifed = date('Y-m-d');
       \Mail::to($user)send(new NotificationMail($user));
       $user->save();
    }
});
```

So if the the script is executed parallel, the slower script `B` would wait on line `$users = \App\User::lastNotified(7)->lockForUpdate()->get();` until the quicker script `A` is done?

Comment: Sidenote: do you need to run processes like these in parallel? Since every process would get all the users and then the gore begins. Why not offload the script to a cron job and let it run daily at 11:00 PM or something? If you have a user base of >10,000 people, then parallel processing is something you can start to think about.

Comment: @Loek you are right, this script will only be executed once a day by a cronjob and it shoul't be run in parallel. I just wanted to cover the case that if forany reason the script might be executed twice not all users get two notifications.

Comment: If you want to cover that case, add a check in your foreach loop. `if ($user->notifiedLately()) { doNothing() }`. But I wouldn't know why a foreach loop would run twice without you specifying it.

Comment: @Loek I'm afraid that adding an `if` request will not solve the issue. A user could then still get two notifications if the script runs parallel.

Comment: But you just said it wouldn't run parallel?

Comment: @Loek sorry than you misunderstood me, I ment that the script should not be called parallel, but I want to still cover it, in case that this might happen. If I could be sure that this will never happen, then I would not need an  ìf` since I only query those who are notified lately.

Comment: Maybe somebody else can answer this :) I don't know enough about pessimistic locking to help you further. My solution would be to make sure that the script will not be called parallel, since that happening sounds like really smelly code.

Comment: Let's see the generated SQL statements.